# VMware Browser base architecture

Tags: browser, vmware

I have a client who is going to start running all of their web apps through the VMware Browser over airwatch.

I need to know what the base architecture is so that I can determine what will and will not work (CanIUse of course does not have this info).

I have looked over the documents and have only found configuration settings and general tech info.

For instance Safari's base is Webkit.

**What is the base for VMware Browser?**

Comment: I saw a response that the base architecture is 'Dolphin' - according to VMWare this is not correct - see the **Answer** below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a web meeting with VMWare techs we did get some answers so I am posting them here for anyone interested.  We **did** find out about the underlying browser technology (**it is not Dolphin**)

### **Update:** We discovered one issue that has affected our applications.  Whenever a user goes into a different office location they sign into that network and we automatically get the IP address and use it to provide services.  **Turns out that the VMWare browser does not accurately report the IP Address - we ended up having to use GeoLocation to determine where the user was located.  Just and FYI

**Q:** What is the underlying browser technology?

**A:** It is **native to each device: webkit on iOs, Chromium on Android**. Browser abilities are tied to the OS (at least in IOS). What they do is basically inject or intercept operations and allow/deny/modify them based on admin settings.

---

**Q:** What kind of tunneling are we doing for VPN?

**A:** There are three kinds:

1. Tunnel Proxy = UI web view (older technology, no longer really supported)
2. MAG = tunnel proprietary logic, views, etc. forced to use UI web view, *performance degradation*
3. Tunnel Client = (new deployment, most features)

---

**Q:** Where are up-to-date release notes?

**A:** Knowledge articles through main portal. More so for IT admin, high level features, bug fixes, but not so developer.

---

**Q:** How often is the technology updated?

**A:**  About every 6 weeks or so.

---

**Q:** How does the browser underlying engine / technology get updated?

**A:** By VMware / Airwatch

---

**Q:** Are there any limits to its features, other than what admins can turn on and off?

**A:** Usually no - should be full featured and remember, features are tied to the device OS.

Comment: While the application uses the built in OS webview, I noticed a few small annoyances with the Android version.  Web applications with gpu heavy tasks were performing much worse than the vanilla webview.  Annoyingly, the remote debugging option appears to be disabled with no available toggle.  Make sure you are still testing your apps in the vm ware browser despite it running the same guts as the built-in webview!

Comment: Wow!  That's good to know, I wonder if that applies to IOS?  IOS is the only platform we use for the vmware technology.  Thanks for the heads up.